# Why Android GLES2 application uses GLES1 runtime?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, irrlicht

I compiled sample Irrlicht GLES2 application and linked with -lGLESv2. But running on Android 4.1.2 device (Huawei Media Pad 10) it outputs in LogCat that it uses GLES1 runtime:

```
01-28 20:47:27.728: I/Irrlicht(9228): OGLES2 initialized
01-28 20:47:27.728: I/log(9228): Using renderer: OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
```

Why this error occurred - I made something wrong during the linking phase, or I should change setting in OS, or it's a bug of my device? Did anyone face this error before?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to use

`mGLView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);`

Comment: have you compiled and run irrlicht in gles2 ??

Comment: Yes, I specified GLES2 in IrrCompileConfig, but I faced texturing errors. So I switched back to GLES1.

Comment: same issue faced by me, texture is not loading in gles2.